# ListViewSubItems in C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, windows-forms-designer

I want to delete some ListViewSubItem if they are checked. I want to remove them from the ListView and from a list (List Products) by the sku.
I´m getting an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if I add 1 to the ListViewSubItem´s index and if I dont´t, I can´t delete the first subitem. Pl hlp.
Thanks.
My code:

```
 int count = lv_list.Items.Count;
 for (int j = count - 1; j >= 0; j--)    
 if (lv_list.Items[j].Checked)
 {
    sku = lv_list.Items[j].SubItems[j+1].Text; 
    lv_list.Items[j].Remove();
    DeleteProductBySKU(sku);
  }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you get that exception when trying to access `SubItems[j+1]` Check if that logic is correct.

Comment: @Guga Yes, there is the problem... how do i get the information saved in the subitem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out via comments, `j+1` is a wrong index for `SubItems`. What you know for sure is that `j` is a valid index for `Items`, but don't have any information about the corresponding `SubItems` (if `j+1` or even `j` are valid). A quick fix avoiding errors:

```
for (int j = count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    if (lv_list.Items[j].Checked)
    {
        if (lv_list.Items[j].SubItems.Count - 1 >= j + 1) //lv_list.Items[j].SubItems.Count - 1 -> last index of SubItems
        {
            sku = lv_list.Items[j].SubItems[j + 1].Text;
        }
        else
        {
            sku = lv_list.Items[j].SubItems[lv_list.Items[j].SubItems.Count - 1].Text;
            //sku = lv_list.Items[j].SubItems[0].Text -> to choose the first SubItem
        }
        lv_list.Items[j].Remove();
        DeleteProductBySKU(sku);
    }
```

The code above takes the last `SubItem` in case that `j+1` is not a valid index. It avoids errors but I guess that this is not what you are looking for. You should update the code to modify the `SubItem` you really want (which should either be a constant value or defined by another counter different than `j`).